# Code to dynamically add number of comboboxes depending on the number of columns in a gridview

Tags: vb.net

I basically wanted to know how we can code to add number of drop down list items depending on the number of column counts in a windows forms application in vb.net.

What I have tried:

Basically i know that you can get a count of all columns in a gridview by using this

```
GridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Count
```

However, i want to know lets say if the columns in the grid view when i run that gridview.rows(0).cells.count call comes out as 15.

I want to use that number 15 and dynamically add 15 drop down objects which will contain three list items: "test1", "test2", and "test3" on page load.

If you require more detail let me know and i will be replying right away.

Thank you and please provide a code and not just a theoretical answer please.

Comment: Add comboboxes where?What will the comboboxes contain?

Comment: VB6 and DataGridView dont go together; `on page load` if that means what it says, you might want to add the applicable web/asp tag (but then, it would be a gridview, not a datagridview).  So, the context for what you are asking is not clear.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks Changed it to vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.Loop and create comboboxes,add items and then add to the control collection.

```
If Not IsPostback Then
  For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Count - 1
    Dim cb As New ComboBox()

    cb.Id = "cb" + i.ToString() //Give unique id

    Dim item1 As New ComboBoxItem("test1", "test1")
    Dim item2 As New ComboBoxItem("test2", "test2")
    Dim item3 As New ComboBoxItem("test3", "test3")

    cb.Items.Add(item1)
    cb.Items.Add(item2)
    cb.Items.Add(item3)

    Me.Controls.Add(cb)
  Next
End If
```

Comment: there is no such thing as a combobox or combobox item in vb.net. Not sure how to change your given code above. is this for a vb.net forms application?

Comment: yes for vb.net forms application http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_combobox.htm

Comment: would there also be a combobox for asp.net? or would the code change if i was using asp.net?

Comment: yes,irrespective of that the logic should be similar.Whether you call it combobox,dropdownlist the code is similar.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Sir @inquisitive_mind

Comment: hey @inquisitive_mind can you please give this question an upvote i am currently banned from asking questions and none of my questions i have asked are bd at all.